# How can I make some links gray while having other links on the page be default?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple navigation bar, but I want the links inside the "navbar" to be gray while keeping the other links on the page default. I can't seem to get it to work right. Can anyone help?

```
<!-- Start Navbar -->
<strong>
<body "link="gray" vlink="gray" alink="gray">
<style>
table,th,td
{
border:5px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
</style>
<table class="center" background="http://cdnleicester.tab.co.uk/wp-content/blogs.dir/41/files/2013/10/black.png">
<tr><td><a href="stonehardlinks.html">Home</a></td>
<td><a href="linklist1.html">Link List 1</a></td>
<td>Link List 2</td>
<td>Link List 3</td>
<td>YouTube Channels</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</strong>
<!-- End Navbar -->
<body link="#0000FF" vlink="#800080" alink="#FF0000" leftmargin="10" topmargin="10" scroll="yes" background="http://thewallmachine.com/files/1345578090.jpg">
<a href="examplelink">examplelink</a>
</body>
```

Comment: I would learn how to properly markup stuff in HTML. You shouldn't use tables for layouts....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.center a { color:#<whatcoloryouwant>}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<style type="text/css">
table,th,td
{
border:5px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
/*replace <strong> wrapping body */
font-weight:700; /*bold*/
}
/*class for all navbar links*/
.center a {
color:#<whatcoloryouwant>
}
/*general links*/
a  {
color:#<somecoloryouwant>
}
</style>
<table class="center" background="http://cdnleicester.tab.co.uk/wp-content/blogs.dir/41/files/2013/10/black.png">
<tr><td><a href="stonehardlinks.html">Home</a></td>
<td><a href="linklist1.html">Link List 1</a></td>
<td>Link List 2</td>
<td>Link List 3</td>
<td>YouTube Channels</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will remember this the next time I make one. :)

Comment: One more thing real quick. I was working on another page and I saw that it was also making my ordered list links gray. Here is the page:

Comment: Hold on. Its too long for a comment. I'll make another question called "Link Color Problem".

Comment: Nvm. I'll figure it out. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: I got it! I combined your code and Amit Jokis code. (With a little editing.) And I got my answer. :D

Comment: Thanks for your help... XD. It says "Only 1 comment per 15 seconds; timer reset"

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
table.center a{
   color:gray !important;
}
```

all others:

```
a{
  color:somecolor;
}
```

BTW, your HTML is invalid

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is right but why have you wrapped the body with strong tag?

Comment: Hey, I'm 13. I have only been doing this for a little while.

Comment: Ok But I would advice you learn the basics first and good luck :)

Comment: I have learned the basics (<table>,<ol>,<ul>,<hr>,<script>,<style>, alert('')(javascript)...(Stuff like that. If it's what you mean.))

Comment: This is not basics. Why not try w3schools it is a good place to learn.

Comment: I will add a basic structure for you here

Comment: Epic fail of epic proportions.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <tile>your page title goes here</tile>
  <meta></meta>
  </head>
  <body>
  your main content for your pages starts here
  <table>
   <tr><td></td></tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Meta is another story first clear your basics